# java regex to extract the image src from the data in the script tag

Tags: java

I need a java regex to extract the image src in the script tag in the following code.help me out..
thanks

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
            document.write('<a href="javascript:popupWindow(\'https://www.kitchenniche.ca/prepara-adjustable-oil-pourer-pi-5597.html?invis=0\')">
<img src="images/imagecache/prepara-adjustable-oil-pourer-1.jpg" border="0" alt="Prepara Adjustable Oil Pourer" title=" Prepara Adjustable Oil Pourer " width="170" height="175" hspace="5" vspace="5">
<br>
</a>');
--></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String mydata = "<script language='javascript'><!--document.write('<a href='javascript:popupWindow"
                + "(\'https://www.kitchenniche.ca/prepara-adjustable-oil-pourer-pi-5597.html?invis=0\')'><img "
                + "src='images/imagecache/prepara-adjustable-oil-pourer-1.jpg' border='0' alt='Prepara Adjustable Oil Pourer' "
                + "title=' Prepara Adjustable Oil Pourer ' width='170' height='175' hspace='5' vspace='5'><br></a>');</script>";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("src='(.*?)'");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Comment: I ned a regex to obtain the image src
I'm not storing it in a string to process.

Comment: @madhuriadhikarla this is a regex. please explain?

Comment: a regex in the sense.. my fucntion needs a regex as argument not the string

Comment: So How are you storing data in java?

Comment: Its a JSONArray
I'm using a selector to extract the data and storing it in an array

Comment: can you share JSONArray with above mentioned data.

Answer (score 0):

This regex finds content of `src` attribute only if `src` is located after `<img`. If `src` is not the first attribute of img tag then you need more complex regex.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "<script language=\"javascript\"><!--\r\n"
                + "            document.write('<a href=\"javascript:popupWindow(\\'https://www.kitchenniche.ca/prepara-adjustable-oil-pourer-pi-5597.html?invis=0\\')\">\r\n"
                + "<img src=\"images/imagecache/prepara-adjustable-oil-pourer-1.jpg\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Prepara Adjustable Oil Pourer\" title=\" Prepara Adjustable Oil Pourer \" width=\"170\" height=\"175\" hspace=\"5\" vspace=\"5\">\r\n"
                + "<br>\r\n" + "</a>');\r\n" + "--></script>";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<img src=\"([^\"]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group = matcher.group(1);
            System.out.println(group);
        }
    }
```

`([^\"]+)` means match any character except `"` and put the match into group 1. In java you have to escape `"`.